# Firebase issues with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to connect my ReactJs app to firebase to implement push notifications. Every time I try to console log the token that I get from firebase, this error always shows up and I don't know how I can solve it. Here is a screenshot of the error :

[image]

I added the following lines in my firebase-messaging-sw.js which is located inside my public file and here it is :

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "msg_id",
})

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging()
```

There is also the file firebase.js and its content which I get the data inside the config object from my firebase project which is already registered :

```
import firebase from "firebase";

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./public/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
        });
}

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAQO5KFxbUnjmoggCRdAkk7wcKXjewRDnU",
    authDomain: "saas-a6939.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://saas-a6939.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "saas-a6939",
    storageBucket: "saas-a6939.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1061462994754",
    appId: "1:1061462994754:web:3ef0dcc11942e042cda2db",
    measurementId: "G-6T9DCBJNME"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

And here is my useEffect where I am trying to print the token :

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
            return messaging.getToken()
        }).then(token => {
            console.log("TOKEN :", token)
        })
    }, [])
```

And here is also my index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './Components/loginPage/Helpers';

const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');

ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I tried many fixes and nothing worked and I still get the same error. I hope that anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual content, such as error messages. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. That will also give you a chance to search for the error message, as this problem has popped up before - and pretty much always has the same solution: figure out why the `/sw....js` URL is serving the wrong content (it is serving HTML in your case), and fix that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your feedback. I will try to do this in the upcoming posts. And how can I know why my firebase-messaging-sw.js url is serving the wrong content and how it can be fixed! Would you pls give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

You need remove from firebase-messaging-sw.js of public and put in firebase.js in one function and register in service-worker.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then(function (registration) {
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
    });}
```

to work with push notifications

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the following lines and edited the post accordingly to show you the file firebase.js after I modified it. Yet, it still shows the same error. Any help pls?

Comment: Have this tutorial to use firebase notification on reactjs https://rharshad.com/web-push-notifications-react-firebase/ if you still having problems you can see my project https://github.com/Warmachine13/BaseAppWebpack